# ERC20 without approve

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-20-approve

Is is good practice if I have a custom-made ERC20 that takes its own tokens out of the user for doing other stuff?

I ask since doing it this way there's no need for the user to call `approve()` beforehand.

And in this way I can write other methods, inside my custom ERC20, that call `_transfer()` without going through `allowance()`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A token where someone else can deduct the balance of the user is not safe.

Any action that causes cost to the user must be initiated by the user.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a practice, as it wouldn't solve the issue of the contract who's method you are calling, (say a routers swap function) from being able to make the `transferFrom` call on behalf of the holder.

Imagine you want to make a swap. If your `move` function doesn't atomically transfer the tokens to the pool contract and call the low level swap function on the pool to receive the tokens, like the router does. Then having what is effectively another `transfer` function isn't very helpful.

The approved contract will be specific to the dapp implementation, it isn't realistic for your token to contain all those use cases.